# Flutter - WARNING **: 10:27:06.760: Unable to retrieve framework response: Message is not valid JSON and Failed to read XDG desktop portal settings

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, deployment

I am currently following a tutorial food delivery app with Dart and Flutter. Since I am new in app development, there is a point where I got stuck. I somehow can not access to a link where there is a data in .json format. Can anybody tell me how I can figure out this issue? Thanks.

File 1: dependencies.dart

```
import 'package:my_app/controllers/popular_product_controller.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/api/api_client.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/repository/popular_product_repo.dart';
import 'package:my_app/utils/app_constants.dart';

Future<void> init()async{
//Load the api client
Get.lazyPut(()=>ApiClient(appBaseUrl: AppConstants.BASE_URL)); //Base link

//Load repositories
Get.lazyPut(()=>PopularProductRepo(apiClient: Get.find())); 

//Controller
Get.lazyPut(()=>PopularProductController(popularProdductRepo: Get.find())); 
}
```

File 2: popular_product_controller.dart (Somehow it does not go into the if statement)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/repository/popular_product_repo.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/products_model.dart';

class PopularProductController extends GetxController{
  final PopularProductRepo popularProdductRepo;
  PopularProductController({required this.popularProdductRepo});
  List<ProductModel> _popularProductList=[];
  List<ProductModel> get popularProductList => _popularProductList;

  Future<void> getPopularProductList()async {
    Response response = await popularProdductRepo.getPopularProductList(); 
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      print("got products");
      _popularProductList=[];
      _popularProductList.addAll(Product.fromJson(response.body).products);
      update();
    }else{
   }
  }
 }
```

File 3: api_client.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:my_app/utils/app_constants.dart';

class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService{
  late String token;
  final String appBaseUrl;

  // Map is for storing the data locally
  late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders; //key and value

  //Constructer for API Client
  ApiClient({ required this.appBaseUrl}){
    baseUrl=appBaseUrl;
    timeout=Duration(seconds: 30);
    token = AppConstants.TOKEN;
    _mainHeaders={
    'content-type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }

  Future<Response> getData(String uri,) async {
    try{
      Response response = await get(uri); //create a get request
      return response; //save the data in response type of object
    }catch(e){
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString()); //if it fails, return the fail and error message
   }
  }
 }
```

File 4: app_constants.dart

```
class AppConstants{
  static const String APP_NAME = "XYZ"; //The name of the app can be changed here
  static const int APP_VERSION = 1;

  static const String BASE_URL = "https://mvs.bslmeiyu.com"; //Domain
  static const String POPULAR_PRODUCT_URI = "/api/v1/products/popular";
  static const String RECOMMENDED_PRODUCT_URI = "/api/v1/products/recommended";

  static const String TOKEN="FKtoken"; // random token for now

}
```

File 5: dependencies.dart

```
import 'package:my_app/controllers/popular_product_controller.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/api/api_client.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/repository/popular_product_repo.dart';
import 'package:my_app/utils/app_constants.dart';

Future<void> init()async{
  //Load the api client
  Get.lazyPut(()=>ApiClient(appBaseUrl: AppConstants.BASE_URL)); //Base link

  //Load repositories
  Get.lazyPut(()=>PopularProductRepo(apiClient: Get.find())); 

  //Controller
  Get.lazyPut(()=>PopularProductController(popularProdductRepo: Get.find())); 
}
```

The path of the .json file: https://mvs.bslmeiyu.com/api/v1/products/popular